# Problem with download method with mega.py library

Tags: python

This code give me a `ENOENT`, Object (typically, node or user) not found,
but in my mega root folder (cloud drives).

I have all of this files:

````
import os
from mega import Mega   
#from base64 import b64decode
```

EMAIL = ""
PASSWORD = ""

credentials = {
    "email": f"{EMAIL}",
    "password": f"{PASSWORD}"
}

def main():
    mega = Mega()
    m = mega.login(credentials["email"],credentials["password"])
    updateTxt()
    
    megaSongs = getFileList(m.get_files())
    mySongs = getTxtSongs()
    print(megaSongs)
    try:
        for song in megaSongs:
            if song not in mySongs:
                downloadable = m.find(song, exclude_deleted=True)
                
                print(f"downloading '{song}'...")
                m.download(downloadable )
                
                    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)                
    
def openStepmania():
    os.system("/program/itgmania")
    
def getDir():
    return os.listdir("Songs")

def updateTxt():
    with open("songs.txt", "w") as f:
        for folder in getDir():
            f.write(folder + '\n')

def getFileList(files):
    extracted = []
    for file in files:
        extracted.append(files[file]['a']['n'])
    
    return extracted[3:]

def getTxtSongs():
    ret = []
    with open("songs.txt" ,"r") as f:
        for line in f:
            ret.append(line[:-1])

    return ret                

main()
````

The output it's:

> ['d', 'e', 'cartella']
> ENOENT, Object (typically, node or user) not found

I try to download a file using `find()` and `download()`, but doesn't find the file, but `find()` works.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).